# Mixing Groovy and Kotlin DSL - how to access extra function

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have an older script which defines a function as such:

```
ext.someFunction = {
   return true
}
```

And I have a new project that uses Kotlin DSL. Now I would like to use that function defined in the previous script. How do I do it with Kotlin DSL?

```
apply("./old_script.gradle")
val someFunction: () -> Boolean by extra
someFunction()
```

results in: `Cannot get non-null extra property 'someFunction' as it does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this wasn't a syntax issue, but rather where I was accessing the function.

This will fail

```
buildscript {
    apply("./old_script.gradle")

    dependencies {
        val someFunction: () -> Boolean by extra
        someFunction()
    }
}
```

But this will work

```
buildscript {
    apply("./old_script.gradle")

    val someFunction: () -> Boolean by extra
    dependencies {
        someFunction()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy closure could not be cast to Kotlin lambda

```
import groovy.lang.Closure

val someFunction: Closure<*> by extra
```